# Prove no continuous function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\text{ with } F(x) = f(x)$ exists for $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ with $x\neq 0$

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, proof-writing

I know that the function defined by $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ can't extend continuously towards the zero.

To prove this, one has to prove that no continuous function

$$F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\text{ with } F(x) = f(x)$$

exists for $x \neq 0$.

How can one prove this?

And how can one prove that  when $f$ with an arbitrary $f(0) \in [-1,1]$ has the feature of the MVT, it means that for arbitrary $a < b$ with $f(a) \neq f(b)$ for every $c \in (f(a),f(b))$ (or (f(b),f(a))), there exists a $p \in (a,b)$ with $f(p) = c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(\frac 1 {n\pi})=f(\frac 1 {n\pi})=0$ for all $n$ whereas $F(\frac 2 {(2n+1)\pi})=f(\frac 2 {(2n+1)\pi})=\pm 1$ does not tend to $0$. So $F$ cannot be continuous at $0$.